# Temporal Order Considerations for Time Series Forecasting with LightGBM

Tags: time-series, lightgbm

When utilizing LightGBM (LGBM) for time series forecasting, is the temporal order of the data relevant? I assume that we must pass the timestamp as part of the input data so that it is able to infer the temporal relationships, but, is it important that the data is ordered? In other words, does LGBM shuffle the data for fitting?